# Generalisation of Hilbert's 90 Theorem

Tags: algebraic-groups, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of fields with Galois group $G = Gal(L/K)$. According to the famous Hilbert's 90 we know that the first cohomology vanish:

$$H^1(G, L^*)=\{1\}$$

My question is why holds [following generalisation](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/david_loeffler/research/galcoho/notes4.pdf):

$$H^1(G, GL_n(L))=\{1\}$$

My considerations:

We have following exact sequence of algebraic groups

$$0 \to L^* \to GL_n(L) \to PGL_n(L) \to 0$$

Applying $H^*(G,-)$ we conclude that $H^1(G,GL_n(L)) \to H^1(G,PGL_n(L))$is injective.

But why $H^1(G, GL_n(L))=\{1\}$?

Obviously it suffice to show that $H^1(G,PGL_n(L))=\{1\}$ or that the induced map $H^1(G,PGL_n(L)) \to H^2(G, L^*)$ is injective. But why one of these two statements hold?

Comment: A reference for Hilbert 90 in this generality is Serre's Book "Corps Locaux", Chapitre X, \S 1, Proposition 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it is true that $H^1(G,\mathrm{GL}_n(L))=0$. One easy way to prove this is to note that this pointed set is classifying vector spaces $V/k$ such that $V_L\cong L^n$. There is only one such vector space.

Note though that $H^1(G,\mathrm{PGL}_n(L))\ne 0$ in general. This is classifying central simple $K$-algebras that become split over $L$, for which there are many for general $K$.

Since the OP knows about algebraic geometry, I can say more. Let $X$ be a scheme and let $\mathrm{GL}_n$ be the normal group scheme associating to an affine $X$-scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ the group $\mathrm{GL}_n(R)$. Then, the etale cohomology group $H^1_\mathrm{et}(X,\mathrm{GL}_n)$ classifies rank $n$ vector bundles on $X$ up to isomorphism. For a Cech covering $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ in the \'{e}tale topology the Cech cohomology group $\check{H}^1(\{U_i\},\mathrm{GL}_n)$ classifies rank $n$ vector bundles on $X$ which become trivialized on every element of $\{U_i\}$ up to isomorphism. For a discussion of this see page 78 of [this](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf).

The relationship now is that $\mathcal{U}=\{\mathrm{Spec}(L)\to\mathrm{Spec}(K)\}$ is a covering of $\mathrm{Spec}(K)$ in the \'{e}tale topology and so $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(L/K),\mathrm{GL}_n(L))=\check{H}^1(\mathcal{U},\mathrm{GL}_n)$ classifies rank $n$ vector bundles on $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ which become isomorphic to $L^n$ on $L$. There is only one vector bundle on $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ up to isomorphism--$k^n$.

The proof of this generalized theorem is just descent theory (in the etale topology) for quasi-coherent sheaves. This is just the (vast) generalization of the Galois descent theory for vector spaces I alluded to in the comments below.

Comment: An element $f\in H^1(G,GL_n(L))$ is a map $g \in G \mapsto f(g-1)\in GL_n(L), f(g-1)^\sigma f(\sigma-1) = f(\sigma g-1)$, it is non-trivial if it is not of the form $f(g-1) = A^g A^{-1}$ for some $A \in GL_n(L)$ (in which case such a $A$ exists only in $GL_n(\overline{L})$). How do you make it representing a class of vector spaces ?

Comment: yes of course when we know that $H^1(G,\mathrm{GL}_n(L))$ parametrizes vector spaces over $k$ such that $V_L\cong L^n$ up to iso then the statement is indeed trivial. Do you have a nice reference or a sketch of the proof why this identification holds?

Comment: @reuns See my updated answer.

Comment: @KarlPeter See my updated answer.

Comment: @reuns Then it's just Galois descent for vector spaces. See this https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf

Comment: For $A \in GL_n(\overline{L})$ let $V = \{  vA, v \in K^n\}$ for $g \in Gal(\overline{L}/K)$ then $(vA)^g = vA^g = (vA^g A^{-1}) A$ so the Galois-action is $v \mapsto vA^g A^{-1}$. How do you see that the Galois action sends $V \to V$ and factors through $Gal(L/K)$  implies $A \in GL_n(L)$ ?